# InvalidConfig: `routes_pathname_prefix` needs to end with `/` on login page

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am trying to make a login page for my dashboard application in dash using flask

**I am trying to run this code but I am getting this error.**

Please tell what should I do and how to resolve this error

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from flask import Flask
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import Dash
from dash_flask_login import FlaskLoginAuth
import sqlite3
import hashlib
from flask_login import UserMixin

# Setup the Flask server
server = Flask(__name__)

# config
server.config.update(
    SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(12),
)

# Create our initial Dash App
app = Dash(name='app1', url_base_pathname='/app1', server=server)

auth = FlaskLoginAuth(app, use_default_views=True)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    ),
    html.A(dcc.Input(value='Log Out', type='submit'), href='/logout', )
])

app.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css',
})

# Run the server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True, port=8050)
```

Answer (score 2):

`requests_pathname_prefix` must end with `routes_pathname_prefix`. If you supplied both requests and routes pathname before this update, make sure requests_pathname_prefix ends with the same value as `routes_pathname_prefix`.

just add "/" at the end. its a standard in the version your using.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0250---2018-08-14)

```
app = Dash(name='app1', url_base_pathname='/app1/', server=server)
```